# mongoose query returns plain javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with mongoose
mongoose queries don't return mongoose document instances

Here is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var AlbumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    cover: String,
    releaseDate: Date,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

AlbumSchema.index({name:'text'});

export const Album = mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema);
```

and this is my query:

```
import {Album} from './Album'

Album.create({
  name:"Eddie",
}).then((album)=>{
  console.log(album);
})
```

result:

```
{ _id: 5a575b82d921be1fc0aa8b44,
name: 'Hogtw',
createdAt: 2018-01-11T12:41:38.711Z,
updatedAt: 2018-01-11T12:41:38.711Z,
__v: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to a mongoose object when creating data, the alternate way is to use .save() method it will return mongoose object in a callback.

```
let album = new Album({ name: 'Eddie' });
album.save(function (err, savedAlbum) {
if (err) {
// show err // 
}
else {
// show response
}
})
```

Comment: you dont get the mongoose object when running the above code?